# Fragment for custom ListView where to write OnItemClick

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I have a layout for `listview` and in fragment i bind it in onActivity created but my problem is which life cycle i should implement `onlistitemClick.

**My code is as follows:**

```
public class HeadFragment extends Fragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;
ListView list;
// The container Activity must implement this interface so the frag can deliver messages
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    /** Called by HeadlinesFragment when a list item is selected */
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.listlayout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // When in two-pane layout, set the listview to highlight the selected list item
    // (We do this during onStart because at the point the listview is available.)
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment) != null) {
        //getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // We need to use a different list item layout for devices older than Honeycomb
    int layout = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), layout, Ipsum.Headlines));
}


//    @Override
//    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
//        // Notify the parent activity of selected item
//        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
//        
//        // Set the item as checked to be highlighted when in two-pane layout
//        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
//    }
}
```

I extends `Fragment` not `listFragment`. Now in which Lifecycle i should write `onListItemClick()` method and how to write it?

Anyone helps me is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're not using a `ListFragment` what you do is set up a click listener that's tied to the underlying `ArrayAdapter`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // do something            
         }

    });
```

listView is just whatever `ListView` you're using in that fragment. You can set this up in the same part where you set the adapter to be associated with the list - which is probably in `onActivityCreated()` or `onCreateView`.

Answer (score 0):

put the following code in `onCreateView()` method. Hope it will help you.

```
ListView list;

//code to get the listView instance using findViewByID etc

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AppointmentListener());
class AppointmentListener implements OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listview, View row, int index,
            long id) {
        Log.e(TAG, "---------------clicked index is: " + index);
    }

}
```